# how to pass a variable thru URL in php

Tags: php

Hi I am trying to pass a value from one file to another file via URL.

The way i do is: `<a href='fund_view.php?idfund="<? echo $row['idfund']; ?>"'>`

after all i get the right value in other file using

```
$aidi = $_GET['idfund'];

echo 'ID= '.$aidi;`
```

But the result i get is this format `ID= \"10\"`

the url after i pass the id looks like

```
http://example.com/fund_view.php?idfund="10"
```

and what i want the result to be is just `ID="10"`.

Comment: remove the " quotes from the anchor <a href='fund_view.php?idfund=<? echo $row['idfund']; ?>'>

Comment: As he has shown, he needs the quotes.

Comment: If you're going to be passing variables through the querystring, it's safer to use `urlencode()` or something similar.

Comment: I haven't seen quotes around values in a URL, it should be `fund_view.php?idfund=10`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
<a href='fund_view.php?idfund="<? echo $row['idfund']; ?>"'>
```

to

```
<a href='fund_view.php?idfund=<? echo $row['idfund']; ?>'>
```

Also keep in mind that your code is quite unsecure... At least cast the parameter to int before using it:

```
$aidi = (integer) $_GET['idfund'];
```

Comment: doing the int-casting presumes that it really is an int. while mentioning security is fine, making a blanket "you must turn it into an int" statement is of no use.

Comment: a field/parameter/column/whatever named ID _should_ be integer

Comment: why? perhaps the op's system requires an alphanumeric id, e.g. 'abc001'. like I said, blanket statements are of no use.

Answer (score 2):

Turn off [magic_quotes](http://php.net/magic_quotes) in php.ini and you should get rid of those backslashes.

Answer (score 0):

Earlier versions of PHP (below 5.4) had an insanely counter-intuitive feature called ["magic quotes"](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.magic-quotes-gpc) which automatically (and silently) escapes all GET/POST strings as if they were going to be used in a MySQL query.

It's relatively simple to reverse, just a headache when you're unaware that such a feature exists.

Solution 1: Turn off magic_quotes with [ini_set](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php)

Sometimes you won't be able to use ini_set (restrictive host providers), so the following is the next best (and portable) solution that I've used:

**NB: function provided on the [get_magic_quotes_gpc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-magic-quotes-gpc.php) function page**

```
<?php
    function stripslashes_deep(&$value)
    {
        $value = is_array($value) ?
                    array_map('stripslashes_deep', $value) :
                    stripslashes($value);

        return $value;
    }

    if (get_magic_quotes_gpc())
    {
        stripslashes_deep($_GET);
        stripslashes_deep($_POST);
    }

?>
```